# Downloading for too long time with gradle in IDEA

Tags: web, intellij-idea, gradle

When I start a new project,it take me too long time to download the whole jar libs(for more than 5 hours),how can I deal with it?

This is the code in my build.gradle file:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Compile

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39'
    compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'
    compile 'org.mybatis:mybatis:3.4.1'
    compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.3.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'
    compile 'org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:1.3.0'
    compile 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.23'
    compile 'org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.2'
}
```

Comment: Buy faster internet connection? It took me about 5 seconds to download all dependencies.

Comment: But my connection speed is about 12Mb/s,can you sure there is nothing else reason?

Comment: It can be your computer, your network, your ISP, ..... pretty much everything that influences download speed. I just wanted to point out that it is not a problem with Gradle or MavenCentral per-se, but specific for you.

Comment: Thanks,I'll try to improve my devices for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the nearest maven repositories for gradle;

add the repositories into builde.gradle:

```
maven{ url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
```

in builde.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven{ url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7")
        classpath("org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.3")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.5-2"
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:docbook-reference-plugin:0.3.1")
    }
}
```

details: https://pingcai.me/2016/12/16/Maven-Gradle-Resolve-Dependencies-%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6%E5%A5%87%E6%85%A2%E6%97%A0%E6%AF%94/